# how to concatenate a string to a numeric,for eg:i need tkr1,tkr2... based on a for loop

Tags: string

```
string str1=tkr;
for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
string str2=str1+i;
sopln(str2);

}
```

I need result like this..
tkr1
tkr2
tkr3
tkr4
tkr5...could any one re-write the code which could give the proper output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not mentioned which language you are using so it would be not possible to give exact answer:

This should work in most of the languages :

```
String str1=tkr;
String str2 = "";
for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
str2=str2 + str1+i + " ";
}
print(str2)
```

And use mutable strings if you are using java

Comment: @SaiPradeep Check out StringBuilder class in java